# Tensorflow return Nan for what should be simple calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to learn tensorflow by going through their tutorial, and making small modifications. I'm encountering an error where making minute changes to their code causes the output to become nan.

Their original code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# training data
x_train = [1,2,3,4]
y_train = [0,-1,-2,-3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

The output of this is:

```
>python linreg2.py
2017-07-22 22:19:41.409167: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.409311: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.412452: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.412556: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.412683: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.412826: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.412958: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:19:41.413086: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W: [-0.9999969] b: [ 0.99999082] loss: 5.69997e-11
```

Note all the messages I get each time I run, because I used pip to install, and didn't compile it myself. However, it does get the right output, with W = -1 and b = 1

I modified the code to this, just adding to the x_train and y_train variables:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# training data
x_train = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y_train = [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

This was the output of this new code:

```
2017-07-22 22:23:13.129983: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.130125: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.130853: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.130986: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.131126: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.131234: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.132178: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-22 22:23:13.132874: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W: [ nan] b: [ nan] loss: nan
```

I really don't know why extending the training data should cause this to happen. Is there something I'm missing?

Also, I'm totally unsure how to debug stuff in TF, like to get the values to print incrementally as it goes along in the loop and changes the variables. Just printing the variables out doesn't seem to work. I'd like to know so I can debug this stuff for myself in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome in the wonderful world of hyperparameter tuning. You could try the following approach, first instead of providing some output at the end, you could also print some output in your for loop, this could then become:

```
for i in range(1000):
    curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss,_ = sess.run([W, b, loss, train], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
    print("Iteration %d W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(i, curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

If you run this then the output looks like:

```
Iteration 0 W: [-2.61199999] b: [-0.84599996] loss: 153.79
Iteration 1 W: [ 2.93535995] b: [ 0.31516004] loss: 554.292
Iteration 2 W: [-7.70013809] b: [-1.79276371] loss: 2020.55
Iteration 3 W: [ 12.6241951] b: [ 2.35030031] loss: 7387.32
Iteration 4 W: [-26.27972031] b: [-5.46829081] loss: 27029.6
Iteration 5 W: [ 48.12573624] b: [ 9.59391212] loss: 98918.8
Iteration 6 W: [-94.23892212] b: [-19.11964607] loss: 362027.0
Iteration 7 W: [ 178.09707642] b: [ 35.9108963] loss: 1.32498e+06
Iteration 8 W: [-342.92483521] b: [-69.27098846] loss: 4.84928e+06
Iteration 9 W: [ 653.81640625] b: [ 132.04486084] loss: 1.77479e+07
Iteration 10 W: [-1253.05480957] b: [-252.99859619] loss: 6.49554e+07
...
Iteration 60 W: [ -1.52910250e+17] b: [ -3.08788499e+16] loss: 9.6847e+35
Iteration 61 W: [  2.92530566e+17] b: [  5.90739251e+16] loss: 3.54451e+36
Iteration 62 W: [ -5.59636369e+17] b: [ -1.13013526e+17] loss: 1.29725e+37
Iteration 63 W: [  1.07063302e+18] b: [  2.16204754e+17] loss: 4.74782e+37
Iteration 64 W: [ -2.04821397e+18] b: [ -4.13618407e+17] loss: 1.73766e+38
Iteration 65 W: [  3.91841178e+18] b: [  7.91287870e+17] loss: inf
Iteration 66 W: [ -7.49626247e+18] b: [ -1.51380280e+18] loss: inf
Iteration 67 W: [  1.43410016e+19] b: [  2.89603611e+18] loss: inf
Iteration 68 W: [ -2.74355815e+19] b: [ -5.54036982e+18] loss: inf
Iteration 69 W: [  5.24866609e+19] b: [  1.05992074e+19] loss: inf
...
Iteration 126 W: [ -6.01072457e+35] b: [ -1.21381189e+35] loss: inf
Iteration 127 W: [  1.14990384e+36] b: [  2.32212753e+35] loss: inf
Iteration 128 W: [ -2.19986564e+36] b: [ -4.44243161e+35] loss: inf
Iteration 129 W: [ inf] b: [  8.49875587e+35] loss: inf
Iteration 130 W: [ nan] b: [-inf] loss: inf
Iteration 131 W: [ nan] b: [ nan] loss: nan
Iteration 132 W: [ nan] b: [ nan] loss: nan
```

At this moment you should be able to see that the values for W and b are being updated to aggressively and instead of decreasing your loss is actually increasing, and approaching infinity quite fast. This in turn implies that your learning rate is way off. If you divide the learning rate by 10 and set it to 0.001 the end result is:

```
W: [-0.97952145] b: [ 0.8985914] loss: 0.0144026
```

And this is then an indication that your model has not yet converged yet (also look at the previous output, ideally you create a plot of the loss. A next experiment where the learning rate is set to 0.05 gives:

```
W: [-0.99999958] b: [ 0.99999791] loss: 6.48015e-12
```

Hence conclusion:

- Try to pull intermediate results out of sess.run() (or the eval() of certain tensors) and look how the model is learning.
- Hyperparameter tuning for fun and profit.

Note: at this moment you are still using 'simple' gradient descent with a fixed learning rates, but there are also optimizers which automatically tune the learning rate. The choice of the optimizer (and its parameters) are also other hyperparameters.

Comment: Thank so much for the help! I definitely feel more on my way, now since I know how to print out intermediate values for things. Still, though, for this learning-rate stuff, seems kind of arbitrary. I understand that the learning-rate is related to the step size, but I honestly don't understand why it would have gone haywire and the loss gone to infinity just because the step size was too large. For this function, the whole gradient is just a constant, so why would that have happened?